# Is there a way to get the repainted area in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8

When calling update() or repaint() with no arguments, everything (including visible elements underneath) is fully repainted. This can be optimized by passing the ClipRect as a parameter. 
Is there an easy way to get the repainted area or I have to determine it manually?

P.S. There is no such problem when using QGraphicsScene, however, I'm dealing with a QmlApplicationViewer and QDeclarativeItems. May be there is a way to force it to the same behaviour for it.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on *Is there an easy way to get the repainted area or this has to be implemented manually.*? What's "this"?

Comment: A bunch of lightweight objects are being drawn on top of an image causing the whole image to repaint. To avoid this, for some of the objects I've implemented a getClipRect() method that returns the minimum rectangle covering the object. This rectangle I then pass to update() method. But, I guess Qt should know the area that is repainted (as it does with a QGraphicsScene), so there is no need to write getClipRect() for every object.,

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an easy way to get the repainted area or I have to determine
>   it manually?

The [QPaintEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintevent.html) object that is passed in to paintEvent() contains `rect` and `region` members that you can examine to determine which part(s) of the QWidget in particular need to be repainted.

Comment: How about declarativeItems with paint(QPainter*, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem*, QWidget*)?

Comment: QStyleOptionGraphicsItem has an 'exposedRect' member that you might find useful, but that appears to represent the part of the item that is currently visible on screen rather than the part of the item that needs to be repainted.  You might need to override paintEvent() of the appropriate widget (i.e. the one that calls paint() on all the items) and cache the rect object of its passed-in QPaintEvent object somewhere before calling up to the paintEvent() method of its superclass.  Then your items could look at the cached copy of that rect.